# angularjs ng-show messes up form validation

Tags: angularjs, ng-show, ng-maxlength

I have an angularjs view with the following input field that is dependent on what organization the user is from..

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': isDirtyAndInvalid(provisionVMForm.vmHostPrefix)}">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="vmHostPrefix">Host Prefix*</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div ng-show="$root.sessionObj.org.name=='orgName1'>
            <input id="vmHostPrefix" name="vmHostPrefix" class="form-control" type="text" 
                 required="true"
                 ng-maxlength="12"
                 ng-minlength="12"
                 placeholder="Host Prefix"
                 ng-blur="setdirtyFromFocus(provisionVMForm.vmHostPrefix)"
                 ng-model="vmHostnamePrefix"/>
                 <div class="pull-left alert alert-danger form-validation-alert" role="alert"
                 ng-show="provisionVMForm.vmHostPrefix.$error.minlength || 
                 provisionVMForm.vmHostPrefix.$error.maxlength>
                     Host Prefix must be 12 characters long. 
                 </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="$root.sessionObj.org.name=='orgName2'>
            <input id="vmHostPrefix" name="vmHostPrefix" class="form-control" type="text" 
                 required="true"
                 ng-maxlength="4"
                 ng-minlength="4"
                 placeholder="Host Prefix"
                 ng-blur="setdirtyFromFocus(provisionVMForm.vmHostPrefix)"
                 ng-model="vmHostnamePrefix"/>
                 <div class="pull-left alert alert-danger form-validation-alert" role="alert"
                 ng-show="provisionVMForm.vmHostPrefix.$error.minlength || 
                 provisionVMForm.vmHostPrefix.$error.maxlength>
                     Host Prefix must be 4 characters long. 
                 </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I need to do is identify what organization the user is currently in, and dependent the org, the hostname prefix input field can only be a certain length. Now, this works perfectly fine when I have just the first ng-show in my code. It correctly identifies the org name and the form complains if the input is less than or more than 12 characters. Whenever I add my second ng-show to identify my second organization.. my first organization form validation for org # 1 is not correct. The form only complains if the input IS 12 characters. I need it to be the opposite. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong by adding this second ng-show? I tried using ng-if when trying to identifiy the organization and that worked fine with the form validation.. but that resolves my vmHostPrefix variable to undefined in my controller. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

ng-show hides the element with display: none, while ng-if will remove the element from the DOM. I think what you have here is a bug caused by having 2 elements with ng-model pointing to the same variable.

Why not do this without repeating so much code and instead try using an expression in ng-minlength.

```
ng-minlength="$root.sessionObj.org.name==='orgName1' ? 12 : 4"
```

Or even better have ui state rules for the org

```
ng-minlength="$root.sessionObj.org.minlength"
ng-maxlength="$root.sessionObj.org.maxlength"
```

I believed they fixed expression evaluations for ng-min max in 1.3

Comment: Thanks for you response! I tried adding an expression in the ng-minlength but It did not work. It is still doing the same thing it did before, not sure what's going on. @cs-NET